# Access parameter of function in promise in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have an AngularJS service that contains the function getServiceData:

```
var DataService = (function () {
  function DataService($log, $http, config) {
    this.$log = $log;
    this.$http = $http;
    this.config = config;
  }
  DataService.prototype.getServiceData = function (fullUrl, qsData, rootNode) {
    var _this = this;
    if (qsData === null || typeof qsData === "undefined") {
        qsData = null;
    }

    return this.$http.jsonp(fullUrl, { params: qsData }).then(function (response) {
        var data = rootNode === null ? response.data : eval("response.data." + rootNode);
        return data;
    });
  };
  return DataService;
})();
```

JSON data is returned, but if I pass a rootNode argument, in the "then" code it is always null. Any idea on how I can access the rootNode argument within the "then" code?

Comment: Hmmm... it works when I assgn a variable var myRootNode = rootNode in the function and use that in the "then" code... why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$http` return promise, from AngularJs [Promise Api](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)

> then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback) – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument: the result or rejection reason.

`then` function take three `callback` function not any valued parameter and it is called after your ajax request completed. So if you want to access any variable or object within `then`, you need to assign outer scope of `then` what you already did in comment.

You should use [angular eval method](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24eval) or @Khanh TO mentioned way instead of JavaScript `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `eval` is unreliable across browsers, that's the problem.

[JavaScript Closure - Eval() and capturing variables in Eval()'s scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503340/javascript-closure-eval-and-capturing-variables-in-evals-scope)

Using `eval` is not recommended. In your case, you should use bracket notation syntax instead:

```
var data = rootNode === null ? response.data : response.data[rootNode];
```

Comment: I agree, you should really just remove "eval" from your javascript vocabulary and never ever use it again.

Comment: The eval is in this case not the problem. If I set a breakpoint, the value of rootNode was null. Reason I used eval was that sometimes I use for rootNode something like Books.Chapters[0]. With eval it works, with bracket notation it doesn't. Any solution for that?

Comment: @Serge van den Oever: strange, `eval("response.data." + rootNode)` should be replaceable by `response.data[rootNode];` . I really have no idea why sometimes it works with eval and does not work with bracket notation.